# How do I set variable values back to a previous state in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Is there a way to "reset" all the values I gave when the keyboard shows? Right now I just hard coded everything but that seems a bit stupid. I hope you can understand my code. I am basically looking for a smarter/faster way to reset all the values, which is in the "else part" of my code.

```
@objc func keyboardWillChange(notification: Notification) {

    guard let keyboardRect = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue else {
        return
    }

    if notification.name == UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification ||
        notification.name == UIResponder.keyboardWillChangeFrameNotification {

        // Keyboard shows
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25) {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            let heightHelper = self.bottomConstraint.constant
            self.bottomConstraint.constant = keyboardRect.height + 20

            self.bottomConstraintEmail.constant += keyboardRect.height + 20 - heightHelper
            self.anmeldenLabel.alpha = 0
            self.logoConstraint.constant = 45
        }
    }else {
        // Keyboard hides
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25) {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            self.bottomConstraintEmail.constant = 337
            self.bottomConstraint.constant = 255.5
            self.logoConstraint.constant = 60
            self.anmeldenLabel.alpha = 1
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen your layout, but I can suggest you two common steps which can make your code look "smarter":

1. Try to place all your views, which constraints you are trying to animate, onto a separate superview. In this case you'll need to have only one hardcoded constant (the distance from this superview to the keyboard top).
2. Make a function like this:

   ```
   func animateConstraint(_ showing: Bool) {
       UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25) {
           self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
           if showing {
              yourSuperView.bottomConstraint.constant += keyboardRect.height
           } else {
              yourSuperView.bottomConstraint.constant -= keyboardRect.height
           }
       }
   }
   ```

...and then call it twice (in your if and else blocks) with different argument values.